# ggplot labels all in wrong location

Tags: ggplot2, label

I'm trying to label a dot plot, but my labels are showing up entirely in a different direction. I though it was due to repelling (tried using ggrepel)- but they are actually just in the wrong location of the dot plot. (it's a volcano plot, so there are no points in the bottom right. Here is my code:

```html
vplot.dM.a <- ggplot(myTopHits.dM.a) +
  aes(y=-log10(p_val_adj), x=avg_log2FC, label = geneID) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  geom_label(data = subset(myTopHits.dNK1, avg_log2FC > 1 | avg_log2FC < -1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.01), linetype="longdash", colour="grey", size=1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype="longdash", colour="#BE684D", size=1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -1, linetype="longdash", colour="#2C467A", size=1) +
  labs(title="Volcano plot",
       subtitle = "dM.a cells") +
  theme_bw()
```

i saw some comments on a similar issue with pie charts, but couldn't adjust it for the dotplot. any suggestions?

plot without labels
[image: plot without labels]

plot with labels
[image: plot with labels]

Comment: Your global data is `myTopHits.dM.a` and your label data is (a subset of) `myTopHits.dNK1`. Using different datasets is going to give a discrepancy between labels and points, but I can't confirm this because I can't reproduce the problem. If so, I'm voting to close the question due to spelling error that is unlikely to affect others with similar problems.

Comment: thank you much. was staring at this for so long and just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`geom_text_repel` function from `ggrepel` should put your label in the right direction. The below code should work. You can tweak the argument the function for better visualization. Also use the same global data as pointed by
[teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand).

```html
 library(ggrepel)
geom_text_repel(
          data        = subset(myTopHits.dM.a, avg_log2FC > 1 | avg_log2FC < -1),
          size        = 5,
          direction   = "x",
          angle       = 0,
          vjust       = 0,
          segment.size = 0.2,
          arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"), type = "closed", ends = "first"),
          nudge_y       = 1 + data$avg_log2FC,
          nudge_x       = 1 + data$avg_log2FC,
          segment.color = "black")
```

Comment: thank you! much improved. and much appreciated!